# Call controller function from other class

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

i have a question:

I have a currently open controller called Login.xib, that has method showErrorPopup that should be triggered when data from server says that login or password is wrong or there is no internet.

But the problem is that my web request is processed in other class file - DataServices.m

The question is, how can i trigger showErrorPopup from other class file?

Comment: Seriously?! None of the other 17 thousand questions called "How to call function in another controller?" answered this already?

Comment: You should use a delegate or completion/error handler block supplied from your login view controller to your DataServices object. Tyt_g207's answer is close to delegation - it just doesn't use a protocol. Blocks are the newer method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a controller in DataServices.m. Declare un variable of type "Login" in DataServices.m, like:

```
@property (nonatomic) Login *myLogin;
```

then when you call DataServices:

```
DataServices *aDS = [[DataServices alloc] init];
aDS.myLogin  = self; //if you call from Login.
```

then, in your function in DataServices.

```
-(void)myFunction {
if (self.myLogin && [self.myLogin respondToSelector:@"afunction"]) { 
    [self.myLogin performselector:@"afunction"]; 
//...
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Cheese,
you can store an instance of Login class in DataServices. So you can call ShowErrorPopUp from by doing for example : [self.loginInstance showErrorPopUP]